# Passing regex string to a assembly

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, .net-assembly

I have this SQL assembly to remove some html-tags from a string. It is working perfectly well for a fixed regex string but I would like to have to regex string as a string parameter when I'm calling the function.

I have tried to pass the regex as a string into the function but it wouldn't work. My guess is that I have to pass it in different format.

Here is the class library.

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class Functions
{
    [SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString RemoveHtmlTags(string inText)
    {

        // Remove html tags other than<p> <b> <h3> <i> <u> <ul> <ol> <li> <strong>
        return Regex.Replace(inText, "<\\s*?\\/?(?!(p|b|h3|i|u|ul|ol|li|strong))\\w*\\s*?>", "");
    }
}
```

And the SQL-function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_RemoveHtmlTags](@InputText [nvarchar](max))
RETURNS [nvarchar](max) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [HtmlTextFunctions].[Functions].[RemoveHtmlTags]
GO
```

What I would like to have is:

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class Functions
{
    [SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString RemoveHtmlTags(string inText, string regexText)
    {

       // Remove html tags other than<p> <b> <h3> <i> <u> <ul> <ol> <li> <strong>
        return Regex.Replace(inText, regexText, "");
    }

}
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: _"but it wouldn't work"_ is not enough an error description. Please add (by editing the question) _how_ it doesn't work. Do you get any errors? If so, what are the messages? Do you get a result that differs from your expected result? If so, please add an example.

Comment: We do not recommend using regex on html because regex stands for regular expressions and html is not regular.  It may work in limited applications but will not work in all cases.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server 2012. When I passed the regex as a string parameter it didn't remove any html tags as it did when the regex was fixed.